# Is there a way to use epel and local yum together

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, yum

I am using RHEL7.

If I do a fresh install of RHEL7(with connected internet) and then installing epel rpm. All the packages are getting installed after that. But then few packages have dependencies and I found those packages are available if I create a local yum.

Whenever I create local yum either it does not work properly or epel do not work. (If local yum works properly epel do not work).

is there any command am not running

Comment: yum looks at all of your repositories to (attempt to) resolve dependencies.  If your local repository has packages with the same name but different version numbering, that can confuse it.

Comment: You can use your local yum with `--enablerepo=reponame`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey maybe, but I was looking for a solution so that it shall not get confused and no conflict shall occur.

Comment: @AvinashRedy could you please elaborate where and how can I use this command to disable and enable multiple repos

Comment: I think you need to clarify the type of problem you are seeing, to get useful answers.  For instance, if the packages which are conflicting are from *another* repository, you could fix that by including that repository.  Or if they are customized packages (only available locally) you are probably better off just using the repository.  You could also try changing the repository priorities using [`yum-plugin-priorities`](https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities), which is available for RHEL7.